# What is the difference between using the service collection to configure settings or adding a singleton in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

On startup of our asp net core applications we read a whole bunch of configuration from our `appsettings.json` and map it to a concrete type that we inject in our service layer.

Consider the two examples below :

**A :** `services.AddSingleton(Configuration.GetSection("Auth0").Get<Auth0Settings>());`

**B :** `services.Configure<Auth0Settings>(Configuration);`

I know using option A I can simply inject the concrete type into my constructor and use it whereas with option B I am required to use the [Options Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Im unsure what benefits option B provides over option A and why I would use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end both approaches give the same result and you cann access an instance of `Auth0Settings` via DI in e.g. your controllers.

For me there are two arguments in favor of the [Options-Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

1. **Expressivness** - you make a clear destinction about application logic
   (services) and configuration (options). This make your code better
   to read and your intent easer to understand.
2. **Flexibility** - the Options-Pattern provides additional features (like
   validation and post-processing)

Although you might not need the additional features the first argument is still on the plate.